# How to render AmCharts as Canvas?

Tags: canvas, amcharts

I am using a charting library, AmCharts to display different types of charts on my web page. Now, I want all those charts to be exported into a PDF. In order to implement this feature, I am using KendoReact's PDFExport Component.

The chart is displayed as a SVG and the PDF Export does not support SVG. Meaning, when the PDF is exported, it does not include charts in it. To fix this, the charts need to be rendered as canvas and not as SVG.

Any idea on how I can convert this SVG to canvas?

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you just answer your own question with the last sentence? If so you should post it as an answer so other people can find it. Additionally, the question is very vague and hard to understand, so you should consider revising it.

Comment: I apologize if I couldn't explain it in an easier way, but I feel you did not read the title of the question. According to my last sentence, I said what the solution should be. But according to the title of this post, I am asking how to do it because I don't know and need help.

Comment: ```The solution to fix this problem ...``` I wanted to point out that the last sentence sounds like an answer. You either need to reword it as a question or clarify why you are providing an answer-like statement in the question.

Comment: I have tried to modify the question, let me know if it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: AmCharts only outputs to SVG. Why not use the PDF export mechanism that's native to AmCharts? It supports exporting mixed content and multiple charts into a single PDF There's a tutorial for this here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/generating-multi-content-pdf-export/

Comment: It looks much better now, @aranderia15. Hope you can get your answer!

Comment: @xorspark there is no specific reason for not using the PDF export mechanism that's native to AmCharts. To be honest, I was not aware about it. Thanks for letting me know, I will investigate it and see if that meets our requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By using chart.exporting.getSVG() you will get the URI format of the chart. then you need to remove the svg type header and decode it back to SVG code before putting it into a canvas.

Here's a snippet of code that might help

```
var svg = decodeURIComponent(chart.exporting.getSVG()._v).split("?>")[1]
canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), svg);
```

You will need the CANVG library to be included on your page.
AMCharts uses this inside their script.

AMCharts built in Export

```
chart.exporting.export("pdf");
```

will trigger the chart to export to pdf (with its own built in SVG to Canvas To Image to PDF converter)

Comment: If you don't want to use the library (I myself have been hitting some issues, perhaps it's conflicting with a different script. Keep getting issues with getBoundingBox() function not found or something. Use this instead :